# Avoid cable modem device limit restriction (MaximumNumberofCPEs)

Tags: router, dhcp, modem, static-ip, cable-modem

The cable modem of my ISP is restricted to four devices. Is it possible to avoid this restriction if i connect a WIFI Router with own DHCP server, static IPs etc. to the cable modem so that I can connect multiple devices to my WIFI Router which uses only one position of my cable modem?

Comment: Using the word restricted can be misleading. Do you mean your ISP only allows 4 devices to be connected simultaneously? Or do you mean the modem is physically limited to 4 ports?

Comment: If you connect networking equipment then all devices would be connected to that equipment not the modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a wifi router plugged into the cable modem, the cable modem thinks only one device is connected. Additionally, all wi-fi routers (that I know of) come with a feature which mirrors the MAC address of your current computer so that the cable modem thinks it is just your same old computer still connected, not a new machine of any kind.

Comment: if doing this he may want to see if he can just bridge the modem. This way he avoids double NATing devices behind the wifi router.

Comment: The config file of my modem says: MaximumNumberofCPEs = 5. Can this be solved by bridge the modem and how can I setup this? thx for that :-)

Comment: This was the solution. I changed the mode of my wifi setup which is plugged into the cable modem to "Router" instead of "Access Point". I enabled the MAC mirror function in my wifi router and everything works now. This is my wifi router http://www.tp-link.com/at/products/details/?model=TL-WR702N#app